# Registering hook in Prestashop module

Tags: php, prestashop, hook

I am trying to register header hook to display my text:

```
//install function
return parent::install() &&
            $this->registerHook('header');
public function hookHeader()
    {
        $this->context->controller->addJS($this->_path.'/views/js/front.js');
        $this->context->controller->addCSS($this->_path.'/views/css/front.css');
    }
```

what that I get when trying to transparent:

[Hooks are already registered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcMe0.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use : `actionFrontControllerSetMedia` / `actionAdminControllerSetMedia` to register yours js and css.

```php
public function install()
{
    return parent::install() &&
        $this->registerHook('actionAdminControllerSetMedia');
}
public function hookActionAdminControllerSetMedia()
{
    $this->context->controller->addJS($this->_path.'/views/js/front.js');
    $this->context->controller->addCSS($this->_path.'/views/css/front.css');
}
```